# reload content in jquery.simplemodal,

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using jquery.simplemodal by ericmartin to show a video. It works fine when I do it once, but if I close  popup and open again, the video no longer works. so i have to reload the page to get it working again.

i used this

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
     // Load dialog on page load
     //$('#myIdShow').modal();

     // Load dialog on click
     $('#myID .wsite-button-inner').click(function (e) {
         $('#myIdShow').modal();

         return false;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you'll need to set the `persist` option to `true`:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myID .wsite-button-inner').click(function (e) {
    $('#myIdShow').modal({
      persist: true 
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```